# regex that i don't understand

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to understand this regex, can you help me out?

```
(?s)\\{\\{wotd\\|(.+?)\\|(.+?)\\|([^#\\|]+).*?\\}\\}
```

- I don't really understand the meaning of DOTALL : `(?s)`
- why the double `\\` before `}`?
- what does this exactly mean : `(.+?)` (should we read this like : the `.`, then `+` acting on the `.`, then `?` responding to the result of `.+` ?

Comment: In the source where you see this, is it in a string literal? E.g., is it really `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?s)\\{\\{wotd\\|(.+?)\\|(.+?)\\|([^#\\|]+).*?\\}\\}");`? It matters, because the backslashes are escapes both in string literals and in regular expressions, so to interpret `\\{` we need to know whether that's `"\\{"` (in which case the `\\` is seen by the pattern compiler as a single backslash which escapes the following `{`) or it's `\\{` (e.g., read from a text file or something), in which case the pattern compiler sees an *escaped* backlash followed by a `{`.

Comment: `.+?` is a non-greedy ("reluctant") `+` operator. `\\\` means a literal backslash, assuming the regex is Java and embedded in a Java string, the first `\\` escapes the second.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This regex is from a string. The "canonical" regex is:

```
(?s)\{\{wotd\|(.+?)\|(.+?)\|([^#\|]+).*?\}\}
```

The DOTALL modifier means that the dot can also match a newline character, but so can complemented character classes, at least with Java: ie `[^a]` will match each and every character which is not `a`, newline included. Some regex engines do NOT match a newline in complemented character classes though (this can be regarded as a bug).

The `+?` and `*?` are lazy quantifiers (which should generally be avoided). It means that they will have to look forward before each character they want to swallow to see if this character can satisfy the next component of a regex.

The fact that `{` and `}` are preceded with `\` is because {...} is the repetition quantifier {n,m} where n and m are integers.

Also, it is useless to escape the pipe `|` in the character class `[^#\|]`, it can be simply written as `[^#|]`.

And finally, `.*?` at the end seems to swallow the rest of the fields. A better alternative is to use the `normal* (special normal*)*` pattern, where `normal` is `[^|}]` and `special` is `\|`.

Here is the regex without using lazy quantifiers, the "fixed" character class and the modified end. Note that the DOTALL modifier has disappeared as well, since the dot isn't used anymore:

```
\{\{wotd\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^#|]+)[^|}]*(?:\|[^|}]*)*\}\}
```

Step by step:

```
\{\{         # literal "{{", followed by
wotd         # literal "wotd", followed by
\|           # literal "|", followed by
([^|]+)      # one or more characters which are not a "|" (captured), followed by
\|           # literal "|", followed by
([^|]+)      # one or more characters which are not a "|" (captured), followed by
\|           # literal "|", followed by
([^#|]+)     # one or more characters which are not "|" or "#", followed by
[^|}]*       # zero or more characters which are not "|" or "}", followed by
(?:          # begin group
  \|         # a literal "|", followed by
  [^|}]*     # zero or more characters which are not "|" or "}"
)            # end group
*            # zero or more times, followed by
\}\}         # literal "}}"
```

Comment: Why do you suggest to avoid lazy quantifiers?

Comment: It should be noted that your regex is not equivalent to the original; the original will match many strings that yours will not. If I had to guess, I would guess that your version is closer to the regex-writer's original intent, but without knowing what the requirements were, there's no way to know for sure. (And by the way, you might as well remove the `(?s)` from your version, since your version doesn't use `.` anyway.)

Comment: No the final `.*?` has meaning because the other pipes also are escaped (which your final regex drops). The regex is looking for a string where the pipe is used as a field delimiter of sorts: `{wotd|field1|field2|some_stuff # possibly a comment?}`

Comment: Oh, and -- I disagree with the claim that "lazy quantifiers" "should generally be avoided". They are often misused by people without a firm grasp on how they work, but if you *do* have a firm grasp on how they work, there's no reason to avoid them. The point about lookahead is a red-herring; the same thing happens with greedy regexes, just in reverse. Either way can (and will) trigger backtracking.

Comment: @user268396 yes, correct... As if it wanted to swallow all the rest of the fields. Fixing to include normal* (special normal*)* at the end...

Comment: Shouldn't the pipes in the middle be escaped too?

Comment: @ruakh fixed for the end. As to lazy quanfitiers, it is not the same at all wrt backtrack as "normal" quantifiers. Lazy quantifiers cost a lot more to process than complemented character classes. They are very, very rarely useful.

Comment: @user268396: I think the `#` is introducing an ordered-list element, not a comment. See http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Word_of_the_day/January_1?action=edit. By the way, fge: at the start of your regex, `\{` should be `\{\{`.

Comment: @ruakh interesting, this means the regex should be simplified a lot (fixed regex beginning)

Comment: @fge: Lazy quantifiers are not equivalent to complemented character classes -- e.g., `.*?x` is not equivalent to `[^x]*x` -- so it's meaningless to debate which one costs more. I agree that lazy quantifiers are rarely useful, but that hardly means they "should generally be avoided". Lots of language features are useful only when they're useful, but no one ever says, say, "`strictfp` should generally be avoided".

Comment: @ruakh I _know_ they are not equivalent. I also know that some regex engines will optimize them away into a... negated character clas if the next regex element is known to begin with a defined set of characters. But one might as well learn to avoid them, since not all regex engines operate this optimization. So, yes, they should generally be avoided.

Comment: @fge: You keep talking about optimization, but if two different regexes behave differently and match different strings, then it's absolutely meaningless to talk about one being more optimal than the other. I suppose you'd also argue that `\p{Alpha}` should be avoided because it's more expensive than `[A-Za-z]`? (And anyway, you're really talking about a micro-optimization. I just tested the regexes `^(ab)*?abc` and `^(ab)*abc` against the string `abababc` in Perl 5.10, and found a speed difference of about 1%.)

Comment: @fge @ruakh thanks, okay and what does `(?:` mean exactly? and `\|` means `OR` or when you say litteral it actually means this symbol?

Comment: @Paul: `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group; it has the grouping effects of `(...)`, but doesn't create a capture-group that could be referred to with `\1` or `matcher.group(1)` or whatnot. `\|` means a literal pipe character; it does *not* mean "or". (By the way, you can also write it as `[|]`, which may be a bit more readable.)

Comment: @fge: I didn't say "more clear", I said "more readable"; and I said that it *may* be: it depends on the person, on the regex, and on the language. (Note that Paul is using a language that requires backslashes to be doubled.) For example, I find `"[(][|][|][)]"` to be more readable than `"\\(\\|\\|\\)"`; you may well find differently, but unless you consider it harmful to even *mention* that `[|]` is a possibility, I'm forced to conclude that you're just arguing for the sake of arguing. ;-)

Comment: @ruakh in fact no. I consider "single character" character classes harmful since they destroy the purpose of character classes altogether. How many examples have you seen that `[ab]` mean that a literal `ab` should be matched? As far as I'm concerned, far too many. So, I prefer to call a cat a cat, as long as people do not understand the _real_ purpose of a character class.

Comment: @fge: "How many examples have you seen that `[ab]` mean that a literal `ab` should be matched?": Honestly? Zero. I don't remember ever seeing that mistake. (I'll believe you that it occurs, though.) Personally, it's not important to me that my regexes be understood by people who don't even know the basics of regexes -- if only because that seems like an impossible goal -- but if you feel differently, then O.K., I'll concede that point. More power to you. :-)